# Some virtual webcams do not show up in the Zoom app on macOS

Tags: macos, webcam, macos-catalina, zoom-meeting, virtual-webcam

Since version 4.6.x the macOS Zoom app has problems with virtual webcams such as SnapCam, CamTwist or VirtualCam. The latest update 5.0.4 should fix the problem (https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201361963). The update indeed fixes the problem for SnapCam but most other virtual webcams (including CamTwist) still do not work (see this discussion for example: https://www.reddit.com/r/Zoom/comments/fuq3wk/camtwist_and_zoom/).

Now I try to find out why most webcams still do not work (the Zoom support is not responding). My first suspicion was that the virtual webcams might need to be notarized. I notarized the CamTwist app on my own but still no luck.

Has anyone an idea why most virtual webcams do not show up in Zoom? Is there maybe a special entry in the `.entitlements` or `info.plist` files necessary? Or do we need to implement specific functions from the `CoreMediaIO` framework?

Regards,

Comment: Apparently Zoom is using a white list of accepted 3rd party signatures. Thus, the only way to get a plugin working seems to be to get into this list somehow.